# Check if object key value exists, if so get another key value

Tags: javascript, object

How do I check if the `"username"` is equal to `"name"` and if it is the get the `"id"`? 
So I'm trying to check if a `name` exists, if it does, then get the `id`.

```
var name="Lisa";
var users = [
    { id:"1234", username:"Claes", room: "General" },
    { id:"5678", username:"Lisa", room: "General" }
];
```

I have tried with this, but I don´t know what I´m missing?

```
for (username in users) {
    if (!users.hasOwnProperty(username)) continue;
    if (users[username]=name) {     
      nameexists = true;
      id = users[id];
      console.log('user exists'+users[id]);
    }else{
      nameexists = false;
      console.log('user does not exist');
    }

}
```

Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your code has a bunch of issues such as treating an array as an object anc referencing elements by id when there is no in the array. If you want to see if the user exists, you can use some `var userExists = users.some(function(item){ return item.username===name});` if you want to get the item[s], filter() is the next option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, the syntax `for (username in users) { ..` is used to iterate the properties of an object, not an array.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

To iterate an array use normal for, the Array's forEach method or the `for..of` syntax (ES6)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Simple solution:

```
users.forEach(function(user) { 
  if (user.username) { // note this will expect a 'truthy' value i.e. except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN
    nameexists = true;
    id = user.id;
    console.log('user exists'+user.id);
  } else {
    nameexists = false;
    console.log('user does not exist');
  }
}
```

BTW: checking equality uses '==' or '===', not '='.

Comment: Thanks, Ovidio. So if I after your code have if(nameexists == true){... then this is always true?